# Was deleting this question the right choice?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75894405/rock-paper-scissors-game-gone-wrong-random-function-error/75894424) (screenshots below) that I answered a few weeks ago was closed as a typo and deleted earlier today.

[image]

And here's my answer:

[image]

I can understand why the question could be seen as being caused by a typo and so subsequently closed, however, I don't think that deletion would be warranted. The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) says:

> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be deleted.
>
> Before voting to delete, please check whether there are any good answers; if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great answers!

I feel that my answer would count as "any good answer" and therefore wouldn't deserve deletion. Two users indicated that my answer was helpful by upvoting it and my answer had no downvotes indicating otherwise (furthermore, neither of those users was OP as they didn't have voting privileges).

So was deleting this question the right decision? If so, then why has the "any good answers" criteria not been met in this case?

Comment: The "any good answer" doesn't protect against deletion, it's to consider whether "the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate." Which Q&A should your answer have been merged into?

Comment: That said, I don't see why something that is essentially "remove `[` and `]`" is a "great answer" worth salvaging. Perhaps you want to extend your reasoning on that? Just going by score isn't that convincing: At leat three people felt the Q&A was worth deleting, more than the two upvoters. Plus, I'm guessing the upvoters were the other two people that felt answering an off-topic question was the right thing to do...

Comment: This sort of situation is why I like to use the comments first for apparent typos. In this case, my form comment would look like: "Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `random.randint([0, 2])`, exactly what do you expect this to mean? In particular, what effect do you expect the `[]` to have?"

Comment: See also now meta-meta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424343/canonical-for-python-parameter-errors

Answer (score 10):

Yes, deleting this question was the right decision.
The help center you linked to, and cited, says:

> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be deleted.

This question has no lasting value. It's a really basic question caused by a simple misunderstanding of the function's parameters. The exact same kind of question has been asked numerous times; keeping this one around is pollution to the site.

There's [4977 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=TypeError%3A+missing+required+positional+argument) about this particular error. This question is not a valuable contribution to Stack Overflow. Please use your moderation tools to close invaluable questions, instead of answering them. Mark as a duplicate if you can find a duplicate. This error is caused by a simple programmer error; failure to comply with a function's signature. The "typo" close reason therefore is appropriate.

Comment: It should neither have been closed nor deleted. It's an excellent archive question, allowing future programmers who make the same mistake to use a search engine search for that cryptic error message. Unless it's a duplicate, in which case it should be closed as a dup. There's nothing wrong with basic questions, nor answers that point out simple misunderstandings of function parameters.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk You frequent the Python tag. Haven’t you, like all the rest of us, seen this exact question pop up again and again?

Comment: I have not, but if it does then at least treat it as a duplicate. The 'typo' close reason was not meant for this case, because it's not a typo it's a misunderstanding.

Comment: Interestingly I'd argue it is a dup of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74718340/randint-missing-1-required-positional-argument-b-code-works-if-i-want-to) question, but the 2 correct answers have been deleted! One looks like it might be a plagiarism deletion, but the other was deleted by the authot.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk No. People are expected to put at least minimum effort into answering their own questions. Checking the signature of the function they are calling is the minimum effort we can expect from them. Any programmer with respect for themselves should have this skill.

Comment: It’s neither a cryptic error message. It’s perfectly clear and self-explanatory. I haven’t used Python in years, and it’s obvious to me what that error is.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship On your minimum effort point, some beginners don't even know what a function signature is unless it is explained to them.

Comment: @MichaelM. Stack Overflow is a site for professional and enthusiast programmers; our standards require minimal knowledge in the field. It is not a tutoring site.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship Not to steer away from the essence of the question, but enthusiasts can't be beginners?

Comment: @MichaelM. They can, but their questions need to follow our standards. I had great use of this site myself, when I was a beginner. The reason this site is so useful, is that it has high-quality questions and answers, that you can search yourself to. These questions hamper that.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk [4977](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=TypeError%3A+missing+required+positional+argument) questions about this particular error. This is not "an excellent archive question".

Comment: A typo caused by a misunderstanding of how to write code correctly, is covered by the typo close reason.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship Beginners cannot be counted upon to understand any of the following words/concepts in the error message: "Type"; "positional"; "argument". In my experience, they also *very often do not logically reason* starting from "the error message says X is required" to arrive at "the problem is that the code does not do X". Surprising if you haven't encountered it before, but.

Comment: From the pile of 4977 "missing required positional argument" questions, there will be (on a conceptual level) a small handful of plausible causes, but not just one. Reference canonicals are useful for most of these, because there are some subtleties. (Though more so for the errors about *extra* arguments, since method calls count an extra one.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel This is why I find SO to generally be unsuitable for beginners to ask questions on. You've probably seen me reference [this question of mine a few times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41569622/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-name). This is also an obscure error message, that doesn't seem relevant to my issue at all. It still doesn't make my question any better. (I've tried to get it deleted several times, several different ways).

Comment: "our standards require minimal knowledge in the field. It is not a tutoring site." It is indeed not a tutoring site, but that is mainly because "tutoring" conceptually involves regular feedback from the student to check that the material is understood. We quite consciously eliminated the "lacks minimal understanding" closure reason a long time ago. Having canonicals for common, *recognizable patterns* of beginner errors is much better than treating each as idiosyncratic (especially as long as the closure system works the way it does, vs FGITWs).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel While I do somewhat agree with you about canonicals for beginner-related questions (pretty much your entire last comment btw), this question in particular is not a good fit for SO.

Comment: "You've probably seen me reference this question of mine a few times. " I hadn't, in fact. But you probably should at the time have been referred instead to a duplicate for "how do I comment code from the middle of a line?" or similar; or else "why is a string on a line by itself seemingly ignored?" or similar. You had an underlying misconception, not simply a typo: you deliberately used the triple-quotes to try to "comment out" the tuple elements, perhaps because you'd seen how docstrings (or other strings-on-a-line-by-themselves) are treated.

Comment: Yes, I do agree that the specific question under discussion is not a good fit. I find that it fails the tests in my answer. It's just that I think my tests are closer to capturing the essence of the best policy here. (As for your question, can't you just delete it yourself if you feel that strongly?)

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk "allowing future programmers who make the same mistake" - how, exactly, would you characterize "the same mistake"? How would they search for it - especially given that they *probably don't know what they did wrong, or else they wouldn't have done it*? The underlying thought process in this question does not appear to be a *typical* thought process resulting in this error message. There are any number of reasons why people do not supply the correct number of arguments for a call. Most of them, however, *won't* look like adding an extra pair of `[]`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Actually, I was thinking of the *exact* same mistake, supply the upper and lower bounds of `random.randint()` as a sequence instead of two arguments.

Comment: Do you think there is something specific about `random.randint` that would cause people to mess up in that particular way? I'm interested to hear your reasoning here.

Comment: "Do you think there is something specific about random.randint that would cause people to mess up in that particular way?" I do not think so. I have seen many questions pop up about it, though. I think it's simply a consequence of it being a highly usual function. It's the language's go-to for random numbers, a language often used as an introduction to programming. I don't find it to be particular in any way.

Comment: /\ Response to @KarlKnechtel

Comment: "but enthusiasts can't be beginners?" - whether someone is a beginner or not is a pretty big red herring and an instant discussion derailer, IMO. Stack Overflow requires personal investment, like the will to learn the basics before you go throwing stuff at walls and see what sticks. What experienced people tend to have as a bit of extra support is that even when they're just trying to outsource effort, they tend to be able to fill in more gaps just through educated guesswork than a beginner might.

Answer (score 10):

> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be deleted.

Here are my heuristics for judging the possible value of a closed beginner-level question:

- If the question is a duplicate, **does it function as a signpost**?

  - Does the *title* of the question accurately describe the *actual problem* that the beginner encountered?
  - Does the question *present* the problem in such a way that someone else with the same problem could *clearly recognize* that it is the same problem?
- Can other beginners **commonly have the same problem**? In this particular case: is there a *reason to expect* `random.randint` to provide this interface?

  - Is it **clear what OP expects** the code to do? From context, it seems like OP expects the returned value to be either `0`, `1` or `2`. However, it *would be just as easy* to mistakenly write this code when *not* wanting the `1` as a possible result: i.e., mistaking `random.randint` for `random.choice`.
  - Is it **clear what OP's reasoning is**? Is there **consistent** reasoning that points at a misconception? When OP wrote the square brackets, why? Why did OP *not* write `int([ai_choice])`, for example? Inconsistencies like this tilt the balance towards judging the problem as an *idiosyncratic* typo, and away from "there is a clear mental model whereby beginners could commonly make this mistake, and therefore there should be a reference canonical to explain why it is a mistake".
- Suppose someone else *did* have the same problem. **How could they search** for the question?

  - Try to imagine the best possible version of the question, edited so that the title looks like the title of a deliberately written canonical. Can you even imagine that, in the first place? Is that title something you could imagine **recalling**, when you encounter someone else with the same question and you want to close a duplicate?
  - Can the problem be **unambiguously described**? If you tried to use an external search engine to look for a canonical for the question, would you expect to drown in irrelevant questions about other topics?